# Remote logging issue with AWS mwaa

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I was testing remote logging to the s3 bucket path to send airflow task logs. Previously it was working fine. We were able to see logs in airflow UI when there was no environment variable set for remote_logging but after setting `logging.remote_logging = True` and giving two more values of `logging.remote_log_conn_id` and `logging.remote_base_log_folder` as environment variables inside `Airflow configuration options` of AWS mwaa. We faced this error.

Error:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /usr/local/airflow/logs/DAG_test/test_mail/2022-11-22T06:42:54.483935+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://ip-10-192-11-229.us-west-2.compute.internal:8793/log/DAG_test/test_mail/2022-11-22T06:42:54.483935+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. timed out
```

We have reverted back the environment variable `logging.remote_logging = False` inside `Airflow configuration options` of AWS mwaa

[image]

still the same issue.
Note: I have not removed or reverted the other two environment variable values.

Any reason or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To help anyone facing the same issue.

It has a permission issue for the S3 bucket for conn_id provided to it via `logging.remote_log_conn_id`. So, after providing access to the given S3 bucket using `logging.remote_base_log_folder`, logs were stored and visible on the Airflow UI as well.